# Is this system linearly stable?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, stability-theory

I am trying to understand linear stability:

- A linear system is linearly stable if all its solutions are bounded as $t \to \infty$.

I have the following linear systems

$x'(t)=Ax(t)$ and $y'(t)=By(t)$ where

$A= \left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1\\ -1 & 0 \end{array}\right)$
and $B=\left(\begin{array}{cc} 2 & 1\\ 0 & -4 \end{array}\right)$

I know they are $A$ is linearly stable and $B$ is not and I am trying to understand why.

In the explanation for $A$ it says since the eigenvectors are independent and from that we can prove that the nilpotent part of the matrix vanishes?

For $B$ I believe it is not linearly stable simply because one of the eigenvalues is positive.

Can anyone explain simply why $A$ is linearly stable to me? If there are no repeated eigenvectors does this normally imply the system is linealrly stable?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, sorry I should have put that down

Comment: Done! Would you be able to help me with the question at all? :)

Comment: I can try (but I am no expert here). I think that a system is stable if all the eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ of the matrix satisfy $\mathrm{Re}(\lambda_i)\le 0$. This is the case for $A$ with eigenvalues $i$ and $-i$, but not for $B$ with eigenvalues $-4$ and $2$. A small component of the initial value in the direction of the eigenvector to $2$ will make the system explode exponentially. Not sure if this is not only stuff you already knew.